# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Angular while running in IIS server under subfolder

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I have created Angular 11 template (Angular 11 + .Net core 5.0) using visual studio 2019. Angular application should be run from subfolder(**caui**) and not from the root folder. I have published the angular application and deployed in IIS. But i am getting following error in the browser.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at runtime.js:1:1)
polyfills.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at polyfills.js:1:1)
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.js:1:1)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Below are the configurations in my project.

Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>tester</title>
  <base href="/caui/" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#3dcd58" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <p>
    You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser.
    Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
  </p>
  <![endif]-->
  <noscript>
    <p>
      This page requires JavaScript to work properly. Please enable JavaScript in your browser.
    </p>
  </noscript>
  <ses-app theme="auto">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </ses-app>
</body>
```

Angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "LowcostCAApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/caui/",
            "deployUrl": "/caui/",
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "LowcostCAApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "LowcostCAApp:build:production",
              "baseHref": "/caui/",
              "servePath": "/caui/"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "LowcostCAApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "LowcostCAApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "LowcostCAApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "LowcostCAApp"
}
```

package.json

```js
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build  --prod --aot --base-href /caui/ --output-hashing none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

.Net core Startup.cs

```js
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ui
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Publishprofile.pubxml

[image: publish profile settings]

Browser network tab trace

[image: Browser Network tab trace]

IIS Server settings

[image: iis server settings]

I am not able to fix the problem.

Comment: Does your project work fine locally? Or does the Unexpected token error occur only after publishing to iis? Usually this error is caused by the jason file, so please check whether the problem is caused by iis first, because it is impossible to analyze your problem based on these error messages.

Comment: Worked when i press f5 from visual studio or run ng serve command. But when i publish the files and try to run it is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Since we make **index.html** like subpath based.  `<base href="/caui/" />`.

Packages are published into `Clientapp/dist/caui` folder. But **index.html** should be placed in `Clientapp/dist` folder location to serve the request.

If i move the Index.html outside from caui folder then it got worked.